# why unicode of arabic and persian chars are the same?

Tags: php, unicode, ascii

i wrote this code in my php

```
echo ord("ت").' - '.ord("ت")."<br />";
echo ord("و").' - '.ord("و")."<br />";
echo ord("ك").' - '.ord("ک")."<br />";
echo ord("ض").' - '.ord("ض")."<br />";
echo ord("ي").' - '.ord("ی")."<br />";
echo ord("ح").' - '.ord("ح")."<br />";
echo ord("م").' - '.ord("م")."<br />";
echo ord("ن").' - '.ord("ن")."<br />";
echo ord("ا").' - '.ord("ا")."<br />";
echo ord("أ").' - '.ord("آ")."<br />";
echo ord("ث").' - '.ord("ث")."<br />";
echo ord("ع").' - '.ord("ع")."<br />";
echo ord("ب").' - '.ord("ب")."<br />";
```

the first are arabic chars and teh second one are persian but the result of the code is:

```
216 - 216
217 - 217
217 - 218
216 - 216
217 - 219
216 - 216
217 - 217
217 - 217
216 - 216
216 - 216
216 - 216
216 - 216
216 - 216
```

this show a lot of chars have the same ASCII code 
i have to detect the language from ascii code but it seems this is not possible!!

Comment: `ord` returns the ASCII value of the first character of string, but the string isn't ascii so you get a problem.

Comment: For the same reason the French and English characters are the same :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Unicode numbers are the same, because Unicode does not distinguish characters by language. Persian uses the Arabic script (writing system), though with additions with respect to the Arabic language, so for example the letter “ت” used in Persian is exactly the same as “ت” used in Arabic, U+062A ARABIC LETTER TEH.

You cannot distinguish between languages by just looking at characters. You can only decide that a given string of characters might be an expression in some languages, which might be a set of dozens or hundreds of languages.

In addition to this, as @Musa remarks in a comment, `ord` is only defined for ASCII characters, and Arabic letters do not belong to ASCII. ASCII is a set of 128 characters, consisting of basic Latin letters, common digits, a collection of punctuation and special characters, and some control characters. So testing with `ord` is useless here.